# Can anyone explain to me, at length, how to use IOC containers?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control

I use dependency injection through parameters and constructors extensively. I understand the principle to this degree and am happy with it. On my large projects, I end up with too many dependencies being injected (anything hitting double figures feels to big - I like the term 'macaroni code').

As such, I have been considering IOC containers. I have read a few articles on them and so far I have failed to see the benefit. I can see how it assists in sending groups of related objects or in getting the same type over and over again. I'm not sure how they would help me in my projects where I may have over a hundred classes implementing the same interface, and where I use all of them in varying orders.

So, can anybody point me at some good articles that not only describe the concepts of IOC containers (preferably without hyping one in particular), but also show in detail how they benefit me in this type of project and how they fit into the scope of a large architecture?

I would hope to see some non-language specific stuff but my preferred language if necessary is C#.

Answer (score 13):

Inversion of Control is primarily about dependency management and providing testable code. From a classic approach, if a class has a dependency, the natural tendency is to give the class that has the dependency direct control over managing its dependencies. This usually means the class that has the dependency will 'new' up its dependencies within a constructor or on demand in its methods.

Inversion of Control is just that...it inverts what creates dependencies, externalizing that process and injecting them into the class that has the dependency. Usually, the entity that creates the dependencies is what we call an IoC container, which is responsible for not only creating and injecting dependencies, but also managing their lifetimes, determining their lifestyle (more on this in a sec), and also offering a variety of other capabilities. (This is based on Castle MicroKernel/Windsor, which is my IoC container of choice...its solidly written, very functional, and extensible. Other IoC containers exist that are simpler if you have simpler needs, like Ninject, Microsoft Unity, and Spring.NET.)

Consider that you have an internal application that can be used either in a local context or a remote context. Depending on some detectable factors, your application may need to load up "local" implementations of your services, and in other cases it may need to load up "remote" implementations of your services. If you follow the classic approach, and create your dependencies directly within the class that has those dependencies, then that class will be forced to break two very important rules about software development: Separation of Concerns and Single Responsibility. You cross boundaries of concern because your class is now concerned about both its intrinsic purpose, as well as the concern of determining which dependencies it should create and how. The class is also now responsible for many things, rather than a single thing, and has many reasons to change: its intrinsic purpose changes, the creation process for its dependencies changes, the way it finds remote dependencies changes, what dependencies its dependencies may need, etc.

By inverting your dependency management, you can improve your system architecture and maintain SoC and SR (or, possibly, achieve it when you were previously unable to due to dependencies.) Since an external entity, the IoC container, now controls how your dependencies are created and injected, you can also gain additional capabilities. The container can manage the life cycles of your dependencies, creating and destroying them in more flexible ways that can improve efficiency. You also gain the ability to manage the life styles of your objects. If you have a type of dependency that is created, used, and returned on a very frequent basis, but which have little or no state (say, factories), you can give them a pooled lifestyle, which will tell the container to automatically create an object pool for that particular dependency type. Many lifestyles exist, and a container like Castle Windsor will usually give you the ability to create your own.

The better IoC containers, like Castle Windsor, also provide a lot of extendability. By default, Windsor allows you to create instances of local types. Its possible to create Facilities that extend Windsor's type creation capabilities to dynamically create web service proxies and WCF service hosts on the fly, at runtime, eliminating the need to create them manually or statically with tools like svcutil (this is something I did myself just recently.) Many facilities exist to bring IoC support existing frameworks, like NHibernate, ActiveRecord, etc.

Finally, IoC enforces a style of coding that ensures unit testable code. One of the key factors in making code unit testable is externalizing dependency management. Without the ability to provide alternative (mocked, stubbed, etc.) dependencies, testing a single "unit" of code in isolation is a very difficult task, leaving integration testing the only alternative style of automated testing. Since IoC requires that your classes accept dependencies via injection (by constructor, property, or method), each class is usually, if not always, reduced to a single responsibility of properly separated concern, and fully mockable dependencies.

IoC = better architecture, greater cohesion, improved separation of concerns, classes that are easier to reduce to a single responsibility, easily configurable and interchangeable dependencies (often without requiring a recompilation of your code), flexible dependency life styles and life time management, and unit testable code. IoC is kind of a lifestyle...a philosophy, an approach to solving common problems and meeting critical best practices like SoC and SR.

Even (or rather, particularly) with hundreds of different implementations of a single interface, IoC has a lot to offer. It might take a while to get your head fully wrapped around it, but once you fully understand what IoC is and what it can do for you, you'll never want to do things any other way (except perhaps embedded systems development...)

Answer (score 3):

If you have over a hundred of classes implementing a common interface, an IoC won't help very much, you need a factory.
That way, you may do the following:

```
public interface IMyInterface{
    //...
}

public class Factory{

    public static IMyInterface GetObject(string param){
        // param is a parameter that will help the Factory decide what object to return
        // (that is only an example, there may not be any parameter at all)
    }
}

//...
// You do not depend on a particular implementation here
IMyInterface obj = Factory.GetObject("some param");
```

Inside the factory, you may use an IoC Container to retrieve the objects if you like, but you'll have to register each one of the classes that implement the given interface and associate them to some keys (and use those keys as parameters in GetObject() method).

An IoC is particularly useful when you have to retrieve objects that implement different interfaces:

```
IMyInteface myObject = Container.GetObject<IMyInterface>();
IMyOtherInterface myOtherObject Container.GetObject<IMyOtherInterface>();
ISomeOtherInterface someOtherObject = Container.GetObject<ISomeOtherInterface>();
```

See? Only one object to get several different type objects and no keys (the intefaces themselves are the keys). If you need an object to get several different object, but all implementing the same interface, an IoC won't help you very much.

Answer (score 3):

In the past few weeks, I've taken the plunge from dependency-injection only to full-on inversion of control with Castle, so I understand where your question is coming from.

Some reasons why I wouldn't want to use an IOC container:

1. It's a small project that isn't going to grow that much.  If there's a 1:1 relationship between constructors and calls to those constructors, using an IOC container isn't going to reduce the amount of code I have to write.  You're not violating "don't repeat yourself" until you're finding yourself copying and pasting the exact same "var myObject = new MyClass(someInjectedDependency)" for a second time.
2. I may have to adapt existing code to facilitate being loaded into IOC containers.  This probably isn't necessary until you get into some of the cooler Aspect-oriented programming features, but if you've forgotten to make a method virtual, sealed off that method's class, and it doesn't implement an interface, and you're uncomfortable making those changes because of existing dependencies, then making the switch isn't quite as appealing.
3. It adds an additional external dependency to my project -- and to my team.  I can convince the rest of my team that structuring their code to allow DI is swell, but I'm currently the only one that knows how to work with Castle.  On smaller, less complicated projects, this isn't going to be an issue.  For the larger projects (that, ironically, would reap the most benefit from IOC containers), if I can't evangelize using an IOC container well enough, going maverick on my team isn't going to help anybody.

Some of the reasons why I wouldn't want to go back to plain DI:

1. I can add or take away logging to any number of my classes, without adding any sort of trace or logging statement.  Having the ability for my classes to become interwoven with additional functionality *without changing those classes*, is extremely powerful.  For example:

   Logging: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/07/31/Logging--the-AOP-way.aspx

   Transactions: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/introducingcastle.aspx (skip down to the Transaction section)
2. Castle, at least, is so helpful when wiring up classes to dependencies, that it would be painful to go back.

For example, missing a dependency with Castle:

> "Can't create component 'MyClass' as
>   it has dependencies to be satisfied. 
>   Service is waiting for the following
>   dependencies:
>
> Services: 
>   - IMyService which was not registered."

Missing a dependency without Castle:

> Object reference is not set to an
>   instance of an object

Dead Last: The ability to swap injected services at runtime, by editing an Xml File.  My perception is that this is the most tauted feature, but I see it as merely icing on the cake.  I'd rather wire up all my services in code, but I'm sure I'll run into a headache in the future where my mind will be changed on this.

I will admit that -- being a newbie to IOC and Castle -- I'm probably only scratching the surface, but so far, I genuinely like what I see.  I feel like the last few projects I've built with it are genuinely capable of reacting to the unpredictable changes that arise from day to day at my company, a feeling I've never quite had before.

Answer (score 1):

I have no links but can provide you with an example:

You have a web controller that needs to call a service which has a data access layer.

Now, I take it in your code you are constructing these objects your self at compile time. You are using a decent design pattern, but if you ever need to change the implementation of say the dao, you have to go into you code and remove the code that sets this dependency up, recompile / test/ deploy. But if you were to use a IOC container you would just change the class in the configuration and restart the application.

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

- http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973811.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy Frey misses one of the biggest reasons for using an IOC container: it makes your code easier to mock and test.

Encouraging the use of interfaces has lots of other nice benefits: better layering, easier to dynamically generate proxies for things like declarative transactions, aspect-oriented programming and remoting.

If you think IOC is only good for replacing calls to "new", you don't get it.

Comment: I purposely didn't mention testing, because he mentioned he is already using DI.  That's all you really need to mock and test.  DI is a strategy; IoC containers facilitate that strategy and make it easier to implement (a reduction in his "macaroni code")

Answer (score 0):

IoC containers usually do the dependency injections which in some projects are not a big deal , but some of the frameworks that provide IoC containers offer other services that make it worth to use them.
Castle for example has a complete list of services besides an IoC container.Dynamic proxies ,Transaction management and NHibernate facilities are some of them.
Then I think you should consider IoC contianers as a part of an application framework.

Here's why I use an IoC container:
1.Writing unit tests will be easier .Actually you write different configurations to do different things
2.Adding different plugins for different scenarios(for different customers for example)
3.Intercepting classes to add different aspects to our code.
4.Since we are using NHibernate ,Transaction management and NHibernate facilites of Castle are very helpful in developing and maintaining our code .
It's like every technical aspects of our application is handled using an application framework and we have time to think about what customers really want.